# Link to “Is it OK to ask questions about immigration?”

Tags: feature-request

Just noticed that when a question is closed because it is about immigration, the banner includes a link to [Is it OK to ask questions about immigration?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-about-immigration)

We don't need yet another discussion on what's off- and on-topic but it seems that no matter where you stand on this policy, pointing to this question to explain it makes no sense. As of writing, it has two conflicting answers, both with a large number of positive and negative votes and a net total of 3 points each. Discussing is fine by me but as long as no obvious consensus comes out of it, how could this discussion be a reasonable justification for any decision? What is a newcomer supposed to make of this? Shouldn't this link just be removed?

Comment: Good point. It's only useful if a newcomer presses us on "why not" but not as an introduction.