# Can we put up links to the expat site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) has now entered public beta.

Can we please put links into the FAQ and the close->off topic options?

Is there an additional way how we could first-time askers to our sister site automatically?

Finally: should we migrate some recently closed questions?

Comment: One thing to remember is that just because it's off-topic here, doesn't mean it'll automatically be on-topic there!

Comment: Generally SE doesn't seem to be fans of migrating legacy closed questions.  But yeah, if you see any you think could be migrated, let the expat meta know and we'll say if it's on topic over there *before* it's moved.

Comment: I don't think SE will implement anything automatic while the other site is in beta. I don't think it can hurt to migrate old closed questions from here but even that should be manual. I **am** in favour of addings links, adding the the FAQ though.

Answer (score 7):

1. Link in the FAQ has already been changed a week or so ago. The immigration close reason has been updated to read:

> Questions about immigration or moving for extended periods of time (studies or employment, among others) are off-topic. Our sister site, [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask. See also the meta post [Is it OK to ask questions about immigration?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1281/793).

This will go live as soon as another moderator approves it.

2. Not that I can think of. Comments always help, and we've already migrated several questions to expats-SE by OP request.
3. Probably, if they are also a good fit for Expats-SE. If you see some good candidates that might find a better home there, just flag and a nearby mod will take care of it. Note that questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated.

Comment: Migrating to beta sites is generally actively discouraged. Better to leave a comment that will ping the asker, encouraging them to reask over there.