# Adding "post this on Expatriates" guidance to the ask page

Tags: feature-request, migration, expat-questions, immigration-questions, asking-questions

### The Problem: Migration Traffic to Expatriates

Adding a migration target to Expatiates isn't currently an available option since SE doesn't add migration paths to sites in beta:

[Migration path between Travel and Expatriates](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/migration-path-between-travel-and-expatriates)

[Why aren't questions that belong on Expats migrated there rather than closed?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/why-arent-questions-that-belong-on-expats-migrated-there-rather-than-closed)

[When should we consider adding a default migration path?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path)

In addition, most of the traffic on Expatiates comes from migrated questions, which in itself could be an indicator of an unhealthy beta.

### The Solution: Guiding Users To Expatiates

One possible solution to this problem could be adding a brief sentence on our ask page pointing askers to Expats. Our ask page currently looks like this:

[image: Travel Ask Page]

Something like

> If your question is about immigration or moving for extended periods of time, [ask it on Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Feel free to post your own ideas as answers.

Comment: You could encourage users to custom flag when a question is being closed with comments saying it belongs on another site. (Or check newly closed / CV-queued questions every day, but that's _yet another manual job_.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 [We have a custom flag like that already](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/migration-path-between-travel-and-expatriates). It works, in the sense that questions posted to the wrong place get closed, but is sub-optimal, in the sense that users don't get otherwise valid questions answered, they get confused as to why their questions are close and what they're supposed to do, and takes up a bunch of everyone's time doing the wrong thing (closing questions because they were asked in the wrong place) instead of the right thing (migrating to the right place).

Comment: Hard to define a dividing line between the two sites.  I’m not a typical tourist in that I like to be there long enough to need things that tourists don’t.  But I am also not interested in “settling down” somewhere.

Comment: @WGroleau we welcome any questions about mid term visas well (anything more than a simple tourist visa would cover), and we also have a few questions related to that.

Answer (score 7):

Some details could be used from the [expats what's on-topc help page](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Shortening the first few of the "what to ask" points might be good enough and not too long:

> If your question is about nationality programs, residence, student, investor and similar mid and long term visas aimed for staying in the country, or complications in every day life due to living in a foreign country as a non-citizen then [ask it on Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

This includes most of the topics of the questions we receive and are welcome there (and are as far as I know off-topic here)

Disclaimer: I'm a mod on expats.SE

Comment: Thanks! I took that paragraph and edited it into our [help] here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic