# Expatriates is leaving beta. Should we finally get a migration path from here to there?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration, expat-questions

There have been longstanding requests for a migration path from here to Expatriates, because we get a lot of questions here asked on a frequent basis that are off-topic here but on-topic there.

The [last time this was requested](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4601/11329), the SE team [agreed that it meets those criteria but declined to implement it](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4606/11329) due to a policy that there should not be any migration paths to beta sites. That post has an extensive write-up on why this site deserves to have that migration path, which I won't repeat here.

Now that the only road-block to implementing the migration path [is going to be removed](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/a/432/14478), should we have this migration path implemented? (It's been a number of years since the last request, so I want to see if it still has the same traction it did at the time as well as confirm that there are no further issues.)

I should also mention that I'm aware of the [recent complaints](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8248/11329) of cross-posted duplicate questions being sent from here to there - this is actually not an issue, since the system [blocks normal users from migrating cross-posted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97632/check-to-make-sure-a-duplicate-does-not-exist-before-migrating/225679#225679). (Migrations done by *moderators* are exempt from this particular check, and mods [aren't notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322776/inform-moderators-migrating-a-question-if-the-migration-would-have-been-normally) if their migration bypassed a normal user check.)

See also: [post on Expatriates Meta](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/should-there-be-a-migration-path-for-questions-from-the-travel-site-to-this-site)

Comment: It's about time! So glad this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go forth and expatriate questions, y'all. This change is live.

[image: Screenshot of the migration modal that shows the option to migrate to Expatriates]

Answer (score 9):

I cannot see any blocks to this being implemented once ExPats graduates. A similar process occurred when Cryptography graduated - they were one of the main destinations for mod-migrations from Infosec, so it was a no-brainer to add them to our fixed migration destinations page. The process here should be equally simple.

Now all we wait for is the graduation, and we can hopefully get it done.

(remind us after the 16th)

Comment: One potential block is if there are objections from the Expatriates community. That's why I also posted the discussion on their meta. A mod there posted "yes" and "no" answers for people to vote on, and currently it's 1-0 in favor of "yes".

Comment: Well, we already migrate good expat questions there (through the mod migration route)

Comment: Yes, and I don't think any of them had been ever closed because they were off-topic. Some might have been duplicates though, but that's fine

Comment: So the graduation took effect today, and [there are no objections on the Expatriates side](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/should-there-be-a-migration-path-for-questions-from-the-travel-site-to-this-site#comment625_433). Can you please put a [meta-tag:status-review] tag on this question so SE employees can implement it?