# Should we close "What would authority/company X do" as primarily opinion based or as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Not too long ago, I reached the reputation level necessary to access the [Close Votes review queue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). This has been a rewarding journey so far; one of the things that puzzled me is the prevalence of questions where we (the Travel Stack Exchange community) are asked to 'predict' what a certain authority would do in a certain situation (most often, but not always pertaining to visas). Examples:

- [Visa schengen processing time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140226/28333)
- [travelling to us with 10 years visa and being asked to carry hospital bills of my us born kids](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140271/28333)
- [How long it takes for the German embassy to remove my details from Database after I drop a mail to rk-info@banga.diplo.de](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140714/28333)
- [USCIS appointments for UK Visas - General Availability](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140611/28333)
- [How strict is Swiss/Edelweiss about pet carrier dimensions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141147/28333)

For more examples of questions recently closed as 'primarily opinion-based', see [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/1071687/questions-recently-closed-because-being-primarily-opinion-based).

While I generally agree about closing these kind of questions, I'm not sure if this is really a matter of *opinion*. I'm wondering if it makes sense to add another off-topic reason boiling down to "we're not Customer Service for authority/company X", like [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/4751173) does.

Closing as primarily opinion-based might be confusing to new readers ("How can this be an opinion based question? They will either get their visa approved or declined.") and it provides the option to link to an extensive meta post which could explain *why* we do not allow these questions and what other resources are available for the author. We already do that for the other three off-topic reasons:

- [What is a shopping question?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question)
- [The WANTA™ debate (We are not travel agents)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents)
- [Is it OK to ask questions about immigration?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-about-immigration)

<sub>(I am aware that the ♦ moderator interface doesn't allow adding more than three boilerplate off-topic reasons. Still, [quite a few Stack Exchange sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/941963/sites-with-the-most-predefined-off-topic-reasons) have done so in the past when the need arose).</sub>

Comment: Interesting to know that up to 5 options are possible. However I'm not sure if Primarily opinion based isn't sufficient enough in this case.

Comment: I should have added some more information about why I think primarily opinion based is suboptimal, but I wasn't thinking clearly yesterday evening ... Now I did.

Comment: Looks like a good plan but I do not have enough knowledge of the site to know how to activate it.

Comment: A request for a fourth off-topic reason would need to go through a Community Manager.

Comment: Some careful drafting would be needed to avoid such a new close reason sounding overbroad. There are also plenty of questions that are _phrased as_ "what would authority X do", but which don't really ask us to predict a case-by-case judgment and can be fully and objectively answered by explaining _what the rules are_.

Answer (score 2):

I think "primarily opinion-based" is fine.  For these kinds of questions, nobody who posts here knows the actual answer so anyone who answers is just posting an opinion.

If the asker finds this confusing, they can ask about it in a comment.